# Datepicker always opening with defaultDate instead of input date with format without DAYS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I would like to reference a solution I struggled to find on the net with jqueryUI datepicker.

When creating a datepicker with these options (assuming fromDate and toDate are 2 date objects):

```
{
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: fromDate,
    maxDate: toDate,
    defaultDate: toDate,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy'
}
```

Whenever you open the DP you will get the default date instead of the previously selected one.

I tried to set the Date with OnClose event which will correctly set the inner date and input date but not the `select option` values.
An example here : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Y8MZ4/

*Fiddle in 1.9 but also tested with jQuery 1.10*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit goes to : http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html

No magic here, you need to manually update the select options.

```
beforeShow: function () {
        if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0)
        {
            iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
            iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
        }
    }
```

BTW, I prefer hiding and showing the Day Calendar during `beforeShow` and `onClose`.

Comment: if anyone has a better solution please submit it :)

Comment: from where do  you take `selDate` value?

Comment: `if((selDate = $(this).val()).length >0){...}` is the same as `var selDate = $(this).val(); if(selDate>0){...}`